# invalid regular expression : illegal repetition in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm practicing regular expressions in java and I have a problem with the line:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\": {\"detected\": (.*?), \"version\": (.*?), \"result\": (.*?), \"update\": (.*?)}");
```

In netbeans I get the error:

> invalid regular expression : illegal repetition

How can I fix the regular expression?

Comment: Repetition in regex can be achieved via `{numberOfOccurances}` or `{min,max}` or `{min,}`. So as you see `{` and `}` are regex special characters and as such they require escaping if you want to use them as literals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the `{` and `}` characters with a backslash (`\`). To get the literal `\`, you need a double backslash (`\\`):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\": \\{\"detected\": (.*?), \"version\": (.*?), \"result\": (.*?), \"update\": (.*?)\\}");
```

Otherwise, it looks like you have a strange (and illegal) repetition expression of the form `{m,n}`, as in `\d{3,5}` (3 to 5 digits).

Comment: I returned the following error: illegal escape character invalid regular expression : illegal repetition

Comment: @NickFuryy ``\`` is special character in String and it also require escaping to create ``\`` literal which you can pass to regex engine. Try with `"...\\{...\\}"`.

Comment: @Pshemo is correct; I have tweaked my answer. Please try it now.